# Why Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) in Agmented Reality Application crashing App?

Tags: android, native, augmented-reality, fatal-error

I am working on Augmented reality app but facing Fatal error issue only on one device (Karbon Android one ) .

My code is working on other device (Samsung) without any  error , but on Karbon it is giving

`Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV)` .

What can be the issue or solution for this ?

In logcat , I cant see any error even `except Fatal Signal 11` ....  I have searched on it and found most of time

`Fatal signal error occur when you are trying to access any object which is not created at that time` , but if it is the case then how my app is running on other device .

Please suggest me the solution .

Thanks..

Comment: This question can't be solved in any way, you should specify the exact problem you have. Also each device has a different configuration, especially native code could behave very different. It may run out of memory and can't create a specific object. I highly suggest you start debugging you app by adding debug lines to any native code you may use. If you use a library you may wan't to report an issue to the creators of it.

Comment: probably it's a memory fault in the native code. You get different behavior from one device to another because of the processing power that they provide. The phone where the app crashes might be too slow and somewhere in your code you are trying to access an object that has not been created yet. This is just an example. If you provided the backtrace of the error probably it would have been easier to identify the issue....